# Finding the difference between the latest and the second latest term

Tags: mysql, sql

The structure of the table is like

```
create table events(
  event_type integer not null,
  value integer not null,
  time timestamp not null,
  unique (event_type ,time)
  );
```

Have inserted few values like

```
insert into events values
(2,   5,  '2015-05-09 12:42:00'),
(4, -42,  '2015-05-09 13:19:57'),
(2,   2,  '2015-05-09 14:48:39'),
(2,   7,  '2015-05-09 13:54:39'),
(3,  16,  '2015-05-09 13:19:57'),
(3,  20,  '2015-05-09 15:01:09')
```

I want to write a query that for each event_type that has been registered more than once returns the difference between the latest and the second latest value .

Given the above data, the output should be like

```
event_type value
2          -5
3           4
```

I can bring out the lowest and the highest using below queries . This is how far I could reach ..confused on the way further .

```
select event_type,value,time from events group by event_type order by event_type desc;

select * from events group by event_type order by event_type ;
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I tried something in [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c05953/6) until I noticed that mysql supports neither common table expressions nor aggregate functions. Wish you were asking for Oracle or SQL Server, that would be pretty easy. I guess you need to work with intermediate view(s).

Comment: @ThomasTschernich How would I do it in sql or oracle .. can you pls provide for sql server .

Comment: Done. See the new answer. Another random hint: Try to avoid words like `value` or `time` for your columns. They are probably reserved words in some/most databases.

Comment: This question is copied from one of codility questions. It should not be posted here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 11):

I modified / simplyfied solution from Shadkhan. Works for MySQL, Sqlite, PostgreSQL

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5827fa/1/0)

```
SELECT e1.event_type, (e1.value - e2.value) AS value FROM
events e1
JOIN
events e2
ON
e1.event_type = e2.event_type
AND
e1.time = (SELECT time FROM events temp1 WHERE
           temp1.event_type=e1.event_type ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1)
AND
e2.time = (SELECT time FROM events temp2 WHERE
           temp2.event_type=e2.event_type ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1)
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't pass some test cases. Test [here](https://app.codility.com/programmers/trainings/6/sql_events_delta/)

Answer (score 7):

With Common table expressions:

```
WITH evt AS
(
  select
    event_type,
    value,
    rank() over(partition by event_type order by time desc) rnk
  from events
)
select
    t1.event_type, t1.value - t2.value
from evt t1, evt t2
where t1.event_type = t2.event_type
and t1.rnk = 1
and t2.rnk = 2
```

Without any CTE

```
select t1.event_type, t1.value - t2.value from
(
select
    event_type,
    value,
    rank() over(partition by event_type order by time desc) rnk
from events
)t1,
(
select
    event_type,
    value,
    rank() over(partition by event_type order by time desc) rnk
from events
)t2
where t1.event_type = t2.event_type
and t1.rnk = 1
and t2.rnk = 2
;
```

Comment: Best straight forward elegant answer of all. I just have one improvement with using row_number() instead of rank() in case there are equally ranked time in the table

Comment: Ok that sounds good as well

Comment: This is the best answer! not the one that have many upvotes! This answer passes all the tests!

Comment: Can also use ROW_NUMBER instead of RANK if you want.

Answer (score 6):

I saw no answer related to MySQL or PostgreSQL. So, here's my approach for doing this and a working solution for MySQL/PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT a.event_type,
(b.value - a.value) AS value
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM   events 
      GROUP BY event_type, time, value
      ORDER BY time ASC
      LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1) AS a , 
 (SELECT *
      FROM   events 
      GROUP BY event_type, time, value
      ORDER BY time DESC
      LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0) AS b 
WHERE a.event_type IN ( SELECT e.event_type
                        FROM events e
                        GROUP BY e.event_type
                        HAVING COUNT(e.event_type) >= 2 )
AND a.event_type = b.event_type
ORDER BY a.event_type ASC
```

Comment: Doesn't work as expected. Gives result for the last event_type. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5827fa/16/0

Comment: Doesn't work properly, as noted above by `deep` comments. Answer from `Jiri Andel` works correctly

Comment: Interestingly, it doesn't work when the query is executed 1-5 times but as soon as its runs 5+ times, it starts giving correct results.

Comment: the part (GROUP BY event_type, time, value) really is not useful to bring you closer to the goal of the question. It aggregates nothing in my understanding, there is no point writing it like that.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't pass some test cases. Test [here](https://app.codility.com/programmers/trainings/6/sql_events_delta/)

Answer (score 4):

**For T-SQL:**

First I try to get each event_type with more than two records

```
(SELECT  e.event_type 
 from events e 
 group by e.event_type
 having count(e.event_type)>=2 
) g --get more than equals two records
```

after that get first records in each event_type

```
(select r.event_type, r.value
 from   (SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.event_type ORDER BY time Desc) AS Group_id,e.*
         from  g left join events e on g.event_type= e.event_type 
         order by e.event_type
        )r 
 where r.Group_id =1 -- get first row of group
)row1
```

then get second records in each event_type

```
(select r.event_type, r.value
 from   (SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.event_type ORDER BY time Desc) AS Group_id,e.*
         from  g left join events e on g.event_type= e.event_type 
         order by e.event_type
        )r 
 where r.Group_id =2 -- get second row of group
)row2
```

and finally join last two query to calculate the answer

```
select row1.event_type , row1.value -row2.value
from  row1 join  row2 on row1.event_type= row2.event_type
```

> and the final answer is :

```
 select row1.event_type , row1.value -row2.value
    from    (select r.event_type, r.value
             from   (SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.event_type ORDER BY time Desc) AS Group_id,e.*
                    from (SELECT  e.event_type 
                          from events e 
                          group by e.event_type
                          having count(e.event_type)>=2 
                          ) g --get more than equals two records
                          left join events e on g.event_type= e.event_type 
                          order by e.event_type
                    )r 
             where r.Group_id =1
            )row1--get first records in each groups
       join 
            (select r.event_type, r.value
             from   (SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.event_type ORDER BY time Desc) AS Group_id,e.*
                    from (SELECT  e.event_type 
                          from events e 
                          group by e.event_type
                          having count(e.event_type)>=2 
                          ) g --get more than equals two records
                          left join events e on g.event_type= e.event_type 
                          order by e.event_type
                    )r 
             where r.Group_id =2
            )row2--get Second records in each groups
        on row1.event_type= row2.event_type
```

Comment: Although perhaps the right answer, code-only answers are not good answers. Please explain your code and how it applies.

Answer (score 3):

As the author asked how I would do it in SQL Server or Oracle, here is a solution that should work in both of them (not in MYSQL though):

```
with cte1 as (
    select e.event_type,
        value - lead(value,1) over (partition by e.event_type order by time desc) value,
        row_number() over (partition by e.event_type order by time desc) xrow
    from t_events e
)
select event_type, value from cte1
where xrow = 1 and value is not null
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9271a/19

What I do is using aggregate functions to both order the rows by date (using the `row_number` function) and calculcate the difference between the current row and the next row (using the `lead` function). After this is prepared I just need to trash the rows that are not needed anymore.

I had to change the create and insert a bit for Oracle (and it would probably need another tweaking for SQL Server), but the select statement should work in both of them.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my query,

```
SELECT a.event_type as event_type,
       a.value-b.value as diff_value
FROM
  (SELECT e1.*
   FROM EVENTS e1,
     (SELECT event_type,
             max(TIME) AS TIME
      FROM EVENTS
      GROUP BY event_type
      HAVING count(event_type) > 1) MAX
   WHERE e1.event_type = max.event_type
     AND e1.time = max.time) a,

  ( SELECT e1.*
   FROM EVENTS e1,

     (SELECT e1.event_type,
             max(e1.time) AS TIME
      FROM EVENTS e1,
        (SELECT event_type,
                max(TIME) AS TIME
         FROM EVENTS
         GROUP BY event_type
         HAVING count(event_type) > 1) MAX
      WHERE e1.event_type = max.event_type
        AND e1.time < max.time
      GROUP BY e1.event_type) max2
   WHERE e1.event_type = max2.event_type
     AND e1.time = max2.time ) b
WHERE a.event_type = b.event_type
```

side note: 
a is max value,
b is second max value 
used https://sqliteonline.com/ to create tables and derive the above query.

Comment: Good logic, though you need to remove the double == and replace it with a single =

Comment: EXCELLENT!!! it passed all the cases, but it can be further beautified by consistent UPPERCASE for SQL keywords and verbs na consistent small case for alias names

Answer (score 1):

**plan**

> 1. use lag variables to calculate value difference over same event type ( using good order by )
> 2. filter where value difference is non-null

---

**query**

```
set @rnk  := 0;

set @lag_ev := null;
set @lag_va := null;

select lagged.event_type, lagged.diff_val as value_difference
from
(
  select ev.*,
  case when @lag_ev is not null and @lag_ev = event_type
       then @rnk := @rnk + 1
       else @rnk := 0
  end as rnk,

  case when @rnk = 1
       then @lag_va - value
       else null
  end as diff_val,
  @lag_ev := event_type as lag_ev,
  @lag_va := value as lag_va
  from events ev
  order by event_type, time desc
) lagged
where lagged.diff_val is not null
order by lagged.value
;
```

**output**

```
+------------+----------+
| event_type | diff_val |
+------------+----------+
|          2 |       -5 |
|          3 |        4 |
+------------+----------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68de9/15)

Comment: Any easy way of doing this .. without using set and all

Comment: its not that complex.. alternative would involve joining to self and some fairly complex logic to find the first and second values ( which would probably also involve variable setters - mysql does not have row_number like functions )

Comment: It would be okay If the query is made for sql server as well ..Can you provide me the way using join

Comment: dont know sql server - but its probably similar to the oracle solution using row_number

Answer (score 1):

I did not know how to work with Rank and all other stuff and went a hard way (PostgreSQL)

```
(select t1.event_type, t1.value - t2.value
from (select event_type, value, time
from events
where event_type in (
SELECT event_type
from events
group by event_type
having count(*) >= 2 and event_type = 2) 
order by time desc 
limit 1) t1,

(select event_type, value, time
from events
where event_type in (
SELECT event_type
from events
group by event_type
having count(*) >= 2 and event_type = 2) 
order by time desc 
limit 1 offset 1) t2) 

union 

(select t3.event_type, t3.value - t4.value
from (select event_type, value, time
from events
where event_type in (
SELECT event_type
from events
group by event_type
having count(*) >= 2 and event_type = 3) 
order by time desc 
limit 1) t3,

(select event_type, value, time
from events
where event_type in (
SELECT event_type
from events
group by event_type
having count(*) >= 2 and event_type = 3) 
order by time desc 
limit 1 offset 1) t4)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT event_type,
                value,
                time,
                Row_number()
                  OVER(
                    PARTITION BY event_type
                    ORDER BY event_type) AS RN
         FROM   #t_events)
SELECT A.event_type,
       ( A.value - B.value ) AS Value
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   CTE
        WHERE  RN = 1)A
JOIN   (SELECT *
        FROM   CTE
        WHERE  RN = 2)B ON A.event_type = B.event_TYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

got the same question on an interview few days ago. This was my answer for it, without using any sub-query.

```
SELECT
  e.event_type, 
  substring_index(substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT(e.value ORDER BY e.time DESC), ',', 2) , ',' , 1)
    - substring_index(substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT(e.value ORDER BY e.time DESC), ',', 2) , ',' , -1) 
    AS value_text, 
  COUNT(*) c 
FROM events e 
GROUP BY e.event_type 
HAVING c > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**For MySQL**

```
SELECT ee.event_type,(ee.value - e1.value) AS VALUE 
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `events` e GROUP BY e.event_type HAVING COUNT(e.event_type) > 1) AS t
    JOIN `events` ee ON ee.event_type = t.event_type 
    AND ee.time = (SELECT MAX(eee.time) 
    FROM  `events` eee WHERE eee.event_type = ee.event_type ORDER BY eee.time DESC LIMIT 1)
    JOIN `events` e1 ON e1.event_type = t.event_type 
    AND e1.time = (SELECT e2.time 
    FROM `events` e2 WHERE e2.event_type = e1.event_type ORDER BY e2.time DESC  LIMIT 1,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this :D

```
WITH CTE AS
 (
SELECT     event_type
           ,val
           ,timee
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY event_type ORDER BY Timee DESC) AS  Stamp


FROM        eventss2
--ORDER BY  price

)

SELECT      event_type
       ,SUM (CASE WHEN Stamp=1 THEN val ELSE  val*-1 END ) AS 'pricedif'
FROM        CTE

WHERE       Stamp<=2
GROUP BY    event_type
HAVING      SUM(stamp)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose such a solution from **SQLite**.

```
drop table if exists events;

create table events(event_type integer not null, 
value integer not null, time timestamp not null, 
    unique(event_type, time));

insert into events
values(2, 5, '2015-05-09 12:42:00'), (4, -42, '2015-05-09 13:19:57'), 
(2, 2, '2015-05-09 14:48:39'), (2, 7, '2015-05-09 13:54:39'), 
(3, 16, '2015-05-09 13:19:57'), (3, 20, '2015-05-09 15:01:09');
```

```
select event_type,
sum(
    case num when 1 then 1 when 2 then - 1
    else 0 end * value) value
from(select row_number() over(partition by event_type order by time desc) num, * 
from events)
group by event_type
having count() > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte_1 as (
    Select event_type,
           value,
           time,
           row_number() over (partition by event_type order by time desc) as time_rank
    from events),
cte_2 as (
    Select event_type,
           time,
           value,
           lead(value, 1) over (partition by event_type) as lead_value,
           time_rank
    from cte_1),
cte_3 as (
    Select * from cte_2 where lead_value is not null)
Select event_type,
       (value - lead_value) as value
from cte_3 where time_rank = 1 order by event_type;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

```
select  event_type, 
        sum(case when Row_number=1 then value when Row_number=2 then -value else 0 end) as value
from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by event_type ORDER BY time desc) AS Row_Number from events) temp
group by event_type
having count(*)>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Also result can be achieved via this query in postgresql;**

```
select t.event_type, t.value - t.leadValue from ( 
select
ev.event_type,
ev.value,
RANK() over (
            partition by event_type
            order by time desc ) AS rank, 
LEAD(ev.value, 1) 
        over (
            partition by event_type
            order by time desc) AS leadValue -- secondEvent
from events ev) t where t.rank=1 and (t.value - t.leadValue) is not null;
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. It would really help our readers if you could explain why and how your answer solves the OPs problems

Answer (score 0):

There are probably betters answers in this thread but this was the first thing that came to my mind the first time I saw this exercise. It actually passed the Codilty's performance tests:

```
select report.event_type,  report.value1 - report.value2 as difference
from 
(select e.event_type, sorted_events.time as time1, max(e.time) as time2, sorted_events.value as value1, e.value as value2
from events e join 
    (select event_type, max(time) as time, value
    from events 
    GROUP by event_type) sorted_events on e.event_type = sorted_events.event_type
where e.time < sorted_events.time
GROUP by e.event_type) as report;
```

Answer (score 0):

Passed the Codilty's performance tests with 100% score:

```
with
a as (
    select a.* from (
        select event_type, value, time
        ,RANK() over (partition by event_type order by time desc) as rank
        from events
    ) a
    where a.rank = 1
)

, b as (
    select a.* from (
        select event_type, value, time
        ,RANK() over (partition by event_type order by time desc) as rank
        from events
    ) a
    where a.rank = 2
)

select 
b.event_type
, (a.value - b.value) as value
from a
join b 
on a.event_type = b.event_type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with base as (
SELECT 
*
,row_number() over(partition by event_type order by time desc) as rankr
from events
)

,step2 as (

select 
* 
, case when rankr = 1 then value else 0 end latest
, case when rankr = 2 then value else 0 end second_latest
from base
where rankr in (1,2)

)

select 
a.event_type
,a.latest - b.second_latest
from step2  a
left join step2 b
on (a.event_type = b.event_type)
where 1 = 1 
and a.rankr = 1 
and b.rankr = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with table1 as (select e1.event_type as et1, e1.value as v1, e1.time as t1, 
row_number() over (partition by e1.event_type order by e1.time desc) as sno 

from events e1 join (

     select event_type 
                
                from events 

                group by event_type

                having count(event_type)>1

                order by event_type) e2

            On e1.event_type=e2.event_type

            order by e1.event_type, e1.time DESC), 

table2 as(
Select *
From Table1
Where Sno<=2)

select distinct et1,
   ((array_agg(v1 order by t1 desc))[1] -
    (array_agg(v1 order by t1 asc))[1]
   ) as diff        
 from Table2
 group by et1
 order by et1;
```

Steps I followed:

1st- Filtering events that occurred more than once

2nd- Ranking filters with serial number based on their time from latest to earliest

3rd- Filtering the latest and second event for each event type

4th- Finally used the array_agg function by changing the sort order of records to calculate the difference

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.event_type--
       ,
       X.value,
       x.rowno,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN x.rowno = 2 THEN X.value *- 1
             ELSE X.value
           END) Valuess
FROM  (SELECT *,
              Row_number()
                OVER (
                  partition BY event_type
                  ORDER BY time DESC)RowNo
       FROM   events
       WHERE  event_type IN(SELECT event_type
                            FROM   events
                            GROUP  BY event_type
                            HAVING Count(event_type) > 1))X
WHERE  rowno <= 2
GROUP  BY x.event_type
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select * into g from events order by event_type, time desc;

SELECT g.event_type, (g.value - h.value) AS value 
into kol
FROM g
JOIN
g h
on h.event_type = g.event_type;

select foo.event_type, foo.value
from
    (select *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY event_type) AS row
    from kol) as foo
where row = 2
```

Comment: It's always good to at least add a sentence or two.  Also please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this question still needs an answer. However, it also took me a good time to come up with a solution while solving on codility, hence submitting my answer too.

Below query is tested in mysql:

```
select * from 
     (select event_type, value-lead(value) over(partition by 
event_type order by event_type) as sub_val 
         from (select value,event_type, dense_rank() over (partition by 
             event_type order by time desc) as rnk from events)a 
 where a.rnk <=2) b where b.sub_val is not null;
```

Explanation:
below query will rank all the values with event type and time.

```
select value,event_type, dense_rank() over (partition by event_type order by time desc) as rnk from events
output:
+-------+------------+-----+
| value | event_type | rnk |
+-------+------------+-----+
|     2 |          2 |   1 |
|     7 |          2 |   2 |
|     5 |          2 |   3 |
|    20 |          3 |   1 |
|    16 |          3 |   2 |
|   -42 |          4 |   1 |
+-------+------------+-----+
```

Next we are subtracting current value with the next one in the row for same event_type

```
select event_type, value-lead(value) over(partition by event_type order by event_type) as sub_val from  (SELECT value,event_type, dense_rank() over (partition by event_type order by time desc) as rnk from events)a where a.rnk <=2
output:
+------------+---------+
| event_type | sub_val |
+------------+---------+
|          2 |      -5 |
|          2 |    NULL |
|          3 |       4 |
|          3 |    NULL |
|          4 |    NULL |
+------------+---------+
```

and finally using the entire query we select everything where suntracted value is not null

```
final output:
+------------+---------+
| event_type | sub_val |
+------------+---------+
|          2 |      -5 |
|          3 |       4 |
+------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This on gives 100% acuraccy in codility testing

```
%%SQL
-- write your code in PostgreSQL 9.4
with cte as (
SELECT
    e1.event_type,
    -- DELTA value
    e1.value - COALESCE(lag(e1.value,1) over(
        partition by e1.event_type
        order by time
        ),0) as value,
        e1.time,
         (select max(e2.time)
            from events as e2
            where e2.event_type = e1.event_type
            group by e2.event_type  
        ) as last_log
from events as e1
where e1.event_type in (
    select 
        event_type
        from events
        group by event_type
        having count(event_type)>1
    )
)
select 
event_type,
value
from cte
where time = last_log
```

Answer (score 0):

A little longer/verbose code, but ensures no duplicates and passes all tests.

In `events_nmb` I use `row_number()` to rank events by descending time.

In `duplicate_event` I filter only events with at least 2 event_type duplicates.

In `events_last` I identify the last occurrence for each event.

In `events_second_last` I identify the second last occurrence for each event.

In `events_last_two_joined` I eventually join `events_last` and `events_second_last` to compute the delta between last and second last values for each duplicate event and return event_type ascending results.

```
with events_nmb as (
    SELECT
        event_type,
        value,
        events.time,
        row_number() over (PARTITION BY event_type order by events.time desc) rn
    FROM events 
), duplicate_events as(
    SELECT event_type
    FROM events e
    GROUP BY e.event_type
    HAVING count(*) > 1
), events_last as (
    SELECT
        en.event_type,
        en.value as last_value,
        en.time as ast_time
    FROM
        events_nmb en
        inner join duplicate_events de
        on en.event_type=de.event_type
    WHERE
        en.rn=1
), events_second_last as (
    SELECT
        en.event_type,
        en.value as second_last_value,
        en.time as second_last_time
    FROM
        events_nmb en
        inner join duplicate_events de
        on en.event_type=de.event_type
    WHERE
        en.rn=2
), events_last_two_joined as (
    SELECT
        events_last.event_type,
        events_last.last_value - events_second_last.second_last_value
    FROM 
        events_last
        inner join events_second_last
        on events_last.event_type=events_second_last.event_type
    order by events_last.event_type asc
)

select *
from events_last_two_joined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with test as (select event_type, (value-lag(value,1) over (partition by event_type order by event_type)) as diffs
, row_number() over(partition by event_type order by event_type )as num
from events where event_type in (SELECT event_type from events 
group by event_type
HAVING count(*)>1 )
order by event_type,time)
select event_type, diffs from test e 
where num = (select max(num) from test f where e.event_type=f.event_type)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
select result.event_type,result.valued from
 ( select sortedevent.event_type,
   sortedevent.value,
   sortedevent.time,
   lag(sortedevent.value) 
   over(partition by sortedevent.event_type)-sortedevent.value 
   as valued, sortedevent.rn from

    (select * ,row_number()
    over(partition by event_type order by time desc)as rn
    from events 
    order by event_type,time desc
    )as sortedevent

    join

    (select distinct event_type,count(event_type) from events
     group by event_type 
     having count(event_type)>1) as event

     on event.event_type=sortedevent.event_type

 )as result
 where result.rn=2
```

1. Group the events by type and date in descending order while maintaining a counter rn for each grouping by the event type.
2. Create a table that has a count of all events that appear more than once.
3. Perform an join to create a single table that has ordered records that appear more than once.
4. Use the lag function to read on previous record to minus from.
5. select the second rn count since it contains the difference from latest two entries.

Answer (score 0):

So here is my solution with ROW_NUMBER(), CTEs & SUBQUERIES (WORKS WITH MYSQL AND POSTGRESQL).

```
WITH TAB1 AS (SELECT *
FROM (SELECT event_type,value,time, ROW_number() OVER(partition by event_type 
        order by time DESC) AS time_rank
      FROM events) AS xx1
        WHERE time_rank = 1),
TAB2 AS (SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT event_type,value,time, ROW_number() OVER(partition by 
        event_type order by time DESC) AS time_rank
      FROM events) AS xx1
        WHERE time_rank = 2)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ab1.event_type, (ab1.value-ab2.value) AS value_all
                FROM TAB1 AS ab1
                LEFT JOIN TAB2 AS ab2
                ON ab1.event_type=ab2.event_type) as TAB3
WHERE value_all IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with CteEvt
as
(
SELECT
event_type,
value,
time,
dense_rank() over (partition by event_type order by time desc) as rnk
from events
order by event_type 
)

select c1.event_type,
(c1.value- (case when c2.value is null then 0 else c2.value end)) as value
 from CteEvt c1
 inner join CteEvt c2 on c1.event_type=c2.event_type and c2.rnk=2
 where c1.rnk=1
```

Answer (score -1):

**That answer working 100% MSSQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite**

```
select 
    Src.event_type,
    (mx.value - SO.value) as value
from 
(
    select 
        event_type,
        max(time) MaxTime
    from events
    group by event_type
    having count(0) > 1
) Src
    inner join events mx on mx.event_type = src.event_type and mx.time = src.MaxTime
    inner join 
    (
        select src.* 
        from events src
        inner join
        (
            select 
                e.event_type,
                max(e.time) SecondMaxTime
            from events e
            left join 
            (
                select 
                    event_type,
                    max(time) MaxTime
                from events
                group by event_type
                having count(0) > 1
            ) as Mx on Mx.event_type = e.event_type 
                    and mx.MaxTime = e.time
            where Mx.event_type is null
            group by e.event_type
        ) as SecondMax on SecondMax.event_type = src.event_type 
                      and SecondMax.SecondMaxTime = src.time
    ) SO on So.event_type = src.event_type 
    order by event_type
```

Comment: Hi Tarik Sengul! Welcom to Stack Overflow, thanks a lot for helping to grow the comunity by provding an answer.  You might not yet know how to give your answers that special 'code look', which help your answer be better understood.  Have a look at the [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for tips!

Answer (score -1):

100% working solution, very short :P

```
SELECT w.event_type, w.difference from (SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by z.event_type) as rnn from (SELECT y.event_type, y.value, y.value - lead(y.value, 1, 0) over(partition by y.event_type) as difference FROM (SELECT * from (SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by event_type order by time DESC) as rn FROM events where event_type IN (SELECT event_type as event_count from events GROUP BY event_type HAVING Count(event_type) > 1 )) x WHERE x.rn < 3) y) z) w WHERE w.rnn < 2;
```